# How to use Library with 1 File on browser solidity?

Tags: solidity, remix, library

I use browser solidity.
Now, I wanna create this C Contract.
[image]

But, I have a message "Deploying and liking required libraries" on the right side of the picture. I have already create Math Library, and I can create Math Library, but I take this message.

What do I do to create C contract on browser solidity?

Postscript：
This is my opinion, the cause is in Bytecode.
[image]

There are "__Math:Math_______________________________" in Bytecode.
I think I should replace this text to the Math Library address, But I can't change Bytecode on browser solidity. Dose anyone know how to solve it?

Answer (score 1):

I'v recreated your example and it works well for me. I have tested the following variations to reproduce without success. Note I have the same (73__Math:Math_____________________________6377) in my bytecode.

- Not naming the file Math to avoid confusing with the name of library.
- having different pragma
- changing function and contract names
- changing the compiler version

So on my side all works fine.

So try the following:

- close your browser and clear your cache and try again : Solidity browser has some habits of not being fully stable
- go in console mode and run the compilation with solc directly, to verify the problem is not in your code rather than solidity
- progressively remove elements of the code (pieces by pieces) and try recompiling + creating the contract each time so identify what exact piece of code is causing the problem.

Personally, now that I have learned the basic of solidity I do not use the browser anymore (only for quick tests) but I am using XCode IDE of Mac os with custom solc builder.

Good luck and let us know the results.

Comment: I succeeded it. I can use that contract wtih browser solidity on Web. I can not use that contract with browser solidity on PC. When I use browser solidity on PC, I have a error message "TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating 'address.toString')". Maybe, this is the cause, but I can not solve it now.